# Edits that end with title edits are easy to lose

Tags: discussion, feature-request, edits, user-interface

I was in the middle of a really big edit on a question. I went to edit the title last, and then somebody else finished editing and the “click to load edit” bar shifted the whole page down and I clicked on it and had to start again.

Maybe the moral of this story is to always use the keyboard to change focus. But could there maybe be:

- a confirmation
- support for drafts
- a better bar placement that doesn’t move everything else

?

Comment: Isn't that normally you refresh/navigate away from a page it ask for confirmation? Pressing the bar should also do the same, shouldn't it?

Comment: I completely agree this can be really annoying.  For the very least your progress on your edit should be saved somewhere. Having your work lost is a very bad incentive for quality edits.